# download link php file

Tags: c#, php

If I don't want to upload content on my server, just link it.

I just want like this :

```
SongID = Cint(Request.QueryString("SongID"))
if SongID = 1 then
    Response.Redirect("http://sound18.mp3pk.com/indian/3idiots/3idiots01(www.songs.pk).mp3")
```

I just got this code from some site.

So how I can make it in proper PHP so it can work?

Example -

```
http://link.songspk.info/indian_movie/0-9_List/download.php?id=79
```

it redirects to - `http://sound18.mp3pk.com/indian/3idiots/3idiots01(www.songs.pk).mp3`

Comment: Excuse me, but that is no PHP.

Comment: @PelletenCate: I think he grabbed code in a random language from some website, and he's asking for it to be translated into PHP.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

    $songid = $_REQUEST['SongID'];

    if($songid == 1)
    {
        header("Location: ".$songLink);
    }

?>
```

Comment: i wrote this '<?php

    $songid = $_REQUEST['SongID'];

    if($songid == 1)
    {
        header('location: http://sound18.mp3pk.com/indian/3idiots/3idiots01(www.songs.pk).mp3');
    }

?>' and tried to open 'domain.com/download.php=1' it shows Not Found

Comment: Presumably, you need to include the http:// scheme. Otherwise, possibly a bad link?

Comment: Try 'domain.com/download.php?SongID=1'

Answer (score 1):

```
header('location: http://sound18.mp3pk.com/indian/3idiots/3idiots01(www.songs.pk).mp3');
```

Comment: i wrote this '<?php $songid = $_REQUEST['SongID']; if($songid == 1) { header('location: sound18.mp3pk.com/indian/3idiots/…;); } ?>' and tried to open 'domain.com/download.php=1' it shows Not Found

Answer (score 1):

header("location:http://sound18.mp3pk.com/indian/3idiots/3idiots01(www.songs.pk).mp3"); should do the trick

Comment: i wrote this '<?php $songid = $_REQUEST['SongID']; if($songid == 1) { header('location: sound18.mp3pk.com/indian/3idiots/…;); } ?>' and tried to open 'domain.com/download.php=1' it shows Not Found

Comment: 'domain.com/download.php?SongID=1